# Problem with output swing in LM358

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, comparator, saturation, inverting-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fodv9n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am working on a battery charger with indicator. I am using a LM358 to compare the voltage of my battery with a reference voltage of 8V from 7808. My input supply is 12V. The battery is connected to pin 2 (inverting input) and 7808 output is connected to pin 3 (non inverting input) of LM358. The Comparator is connected to 12V VCC through a 4.7k Resistor. Indicator LED is connected on pin 1 of LM358.

The expected output is that once the battery crosses 8V, the output of the comparator must swing low and LED will turn OFF. Initially, the output is high and LED glows as expected. But when the inverting pin crosses 8V, the output doesn't swing (High to low). However, when I touch any metal part to any component (lead of the component), the output swings low (from High) and LED goes OFF. But this doesn't happen automatically, every time I touch a metal I see the swing.I want this to happen automatically.

And if the battery is above 8V, and when I connect it for charging, the LED does not glow; which is correct. It is just the transition from High to Low I need. Can anyone help/suggest me what am I missing here?

Note: LM358 is used in open loop configuration and no feedback is given.

P.S.: I have inserted the schematic. Sorry if it is not clear, I am new to the interface.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're really going to have to at least show us your schematic if you seriously expect any help.

Comment: *The battery is connected to pin 2 (inverting input)...* Welcome to this site! We really like schematics here so we have a tool to draw them. Edit your question and add a schematic, you can also include a picture of as long as it is clear enough. No schematic, no answer I'm afraid.

Comment: hello, I've added the schematic. Hope now I can get the help :p

Comment: hm, what is the negative supply pin of your LM358 connected to?

Comment: Why do you have R3 sitting in series with the supply of the LM358? I would remove it. Saying *the inverting pin crosses 8V* is confusing, the crossing itself isn't relevant, the situation **after the crossing** is. So you better write: the inverting pin is at a voltage above / below 8 V.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie oops I didn't even notice that one. New_user, how did you come up with this schematic? R1 and D1 make no sense at all, but waste power, R3 makes no sense at all, it's doubtful R2 has a sensible value, the negative supply of your opamp isn't connected – this looks like you didn't *design* a circuit based on an understanding of what your resistors, diodes and opamp do, but based on wild guessing. I'm really not sure we can salvage any of it.

Comment: The battery is getting charged, so its variable. Sorry if crossing confuses you. When the voltage is above 8V the comparator must get low, but that doesn't happen. My concern is it happens only when a metal part is touched to any lead in the circuit, I see the transition. Is it some noise? static electricity?

Comment: your circuit simply doesn't make sense and hence doesn't work – this is not a noise problem. You've basically build a car where the motor sits on the front seat, isn't connected to the gas tank at all, and are complaining that your car only moves if parked downhill, and whether that's a problem with the tire pressure.

Comment: @marcus I have used the resistor and diode to limit the current and protection for my supply respectively. I do understand R3 was not required, but still I didn't wanted my output to swing till 12V. I will eliminate R3 only if someone can assure me that is what causing the problem.

Comment: _"I will eliminate R3 only if someone can assure me that is what causing the problem"_ I sense this will not bode well for getting help here.

Comment: What @winny said. R3 is part of your circuit's problem. So are R1, R2, R3, D1 and the LM358. *your circuit makes no sense. A single modification won't rescue it, but if you can't take recommendations to fix your circuit, well, you gotta leave it broken.*

Comment: Guys, I am trying to charge the battery with limited current and trying to use cheap components. R1 and D1 does not produce any issue since it controls current in the circuit. Although, it dissipates a lot of POWER, I understand that. But the problem is with the transition of my LM358's output.

Comment: *I will eliminate R3 only if someone can assure me that is what causing the problem* R3 **is** a problem. Using a resistor, especially such a high value one, in the supply line is "silly", it serves no purpose. It is not said that that is the **only** problem this circuit has, there might be more. Example: if D1 is **really** a 1N4148 then for sure it will break itself as the current through it is more than double what a 1N4148 can handle.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, I get that and will take that advice and try without the R3. But have you seen a case as of yet, the transition from High to low happens only when there is a metal contact to the leads of the active components?

Comment: How is that metal contact behavior in any way relevant when the circuit itself is flawed? Having R3 in place can result in all kinds of weird and **unpredictable** behavior because the LM358 is not designed to work with a 4.7 k resistor to 12 V in its positive supply rail. Probably it will get its supply voltage through its - input via the internal ESD diodes. That is not the proper way to use an opamp so there's no need to discuss it. Use an opamp properly first and then we can discuss it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie sure, I'll try that and get back. Thanks for the suggestion guys. :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller the negative of the comparator is connected to Ground. i.e. the pin 4 of LM358. Sorry, forgot to show the connection.

Comment: Your comparator is comparing 8 volts with 8 volts. What's that all about?

Comment: @Andyaka the comparator compares the reference voltage of 8V with the battery voltage which will go above 8V. So, basically when battery voltage will be 8.01 or above, the comparator output must go low.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the diode I used in my circuit is 1N5408 and it can handle the current. My circuit aloows 0.3A of current. (Don't ask how ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current driving the LED has to come through R2 (1 kohm). That's fed by the LM358 from its power pin, which means it has to come through R3 (4.7 kohm).  That's part of the problem. 5.7 kohm in series with a LED would probably still light it OK, but I suspect that when the LED is on the 358 browns out and stops working until the supply voltage recovers. If you really want R3 in there, try 4.7 ohm instead of 4.7 kohm.

Comment: Yes, I eliminated the 4.7K in the circuit and connected my comparator directly to 12V. And Voila! it worked. That was silly of me to use a 4.7K, I was working with some different logic/reason with that Resistor. I just need to check it with my battery completely discharged and see how much time it takes to reach the reference and get the transition.Thanks to all the guys for your valuable information and support. And do I need to update the schematic?